# Call a protected method from outside a class in PHP

Tags: php, access-modifiers

I have a very special case in which I need to call a protected method from outside a class. I am very conscious about what I do programmingwise, but I would not be entirely opposed to doing so in this one special case I have. In all other cases, I need to continue disallowing access to the internal method, and so I would like to keep the method protected.

What are some elegant ways to access a protected method outside of a class? So far, I've found [this](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34044).

I suppose it may be possible create some kind of double-agent instance of the target class that would sneakily provide access to the internals...

Comment: Best way to do it?  Change the function to be public.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP you can do this using Reflections.
To invoke protected or private methods use the setAccessible() method 
http://php.net/reflectionmethod.setaccessible (just set it to TRUE)

Comment: You should tell how to do the thing as an answer, not to link some  other answer (in this case, documentation). You are, though, encouraged to link to your source and other important bits of documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I would think that in this case, refactoring so you don't require this sort of thing is probably the most elegant way to go. In saying that one option is to use `__call` and within that parse `debug_backtrace` to see which class called the method. Then check a friends whitelst

```
class ProtectedClass {

    // Friend list
    private $friends = array('secret' => array('FriendClass')); 

    protected function secret($arg1, $arg2) {
        // ...
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {

        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        $class = $trace[1]['class'];
        if(in_array($class, $this->friends[$method]))
            return $this->$method($args[0], $args[1]);

        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

I think I need a shower.

Comment: Why not just use reflections?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little kludgy, but might be an option.

Add a child class for the sake of accessing your protected function

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public function protectedFunc() {
        return parent::protectedFunc();
    }
}
```

Then, instantiate an instance of `Child` instead of `Parent` where you need to call that function.

Comment: Hmm, yea, this looks like my only option at this point. Maybe I should call this class Spy o_O.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing this out there since I haven't programmed in PHP in two years.  Could you just add a function to the class that calls the protected method like so?

```
$obj->publicFunc = create_function('$arg', 'return $this->protectedFunc($arg);');
```

**Edit**: 
**I think Tom's correct in looking at the documentation for create_function.  It looks like the scope of $this will be "wrong" when you try to call it with this example.**

---

It looks like traditional anonymous functions are supported since PHP 5.3.0 as well (and my first solution probably won't work), so I'd probably write it like this instead:

```
$obj->publicFunc = function($arg) { 
     return $this->protectedFunc($arg); 
};
```

Since I think it looks a little cleaner (and your IDE of choice will highlight it better of course).

---

Ugh, I tried using [Reflection](http://us.php.net/oop5.reflection) to call the method but PHP won't allow you to do that either.  It seems that you're going to have to use some sort of child class like the other posters have suggested.  If you find a method that works, the developers will likely classify it as a bug in the future and break your code when you upgrade to the next version.

I recommend extending the class.

Comment: Nono, it's a good shot. I'll probably give that a try. If it works, I'll let you know.

Comment: I think this will just create a string $obj->publicFunc which is the name of the new function. When you try to call it the scope is as for a normal function.

Comment: I'm not getting this working: http://chadjohnson.ath.cx:8080/static/anonymous_function.phps. The error I get is "Call to undefined method Chad::publicFunction()." What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Reflection is a good idea, in 5.3 you could use setAccessible() to let you call a protected method

Comment: Good to know. Turns out I don't need to access this protected method...thank goodness. I learned things though!

Comment: Tom: setAccessible() is only available on the ReflectionProperty class.  If you try to create a new ReflectionProperty where bar is the method and foo is the class name you will get this error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Property foo::$bar does not exist'.  If only you could do it on methods too...

Comment: Like @ChadJohnson I get "Call to undefined method". It seems that this process does not define a method. Waste of time. Use reflection instead.

Comment: @DaveL, you can do it on methods, by using ReflectionMethod instead of ReflectionProperty.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think about what is the matter with the program design if I have to call a private function?

It used to be the case when

- your class is responsible for several things (it is really two or thre calsses wrapped together) or
- the rules of encapsulation are broken (utility functions, for example)

By finding *any* way to walk around this questions, you'll be nowhere nearer to the real solution.

Comment: In general this is good advice. But sometimes there are good reasons for calling methods outside their defined scope. For example, if you don't want to make a method part of your API, but you want to call it in your tests. Or in CodeIgniter views, you might want your password hash function not to be callable from the web, but you do want to call them in your tests. Unlike C++, PHP doesn't have "friend" classes that have privileged access to class internals.

Comment: Also if you're using some third-party API which doesn't expose the method, but you definitely do need access to that method. Definitely a valid point made by Csaba, but on very rare occasions, you may have to break the rules.

Answer (score -3):

Suppose your method declaration goes like so:

```
protected function getTheFoo() {
    ...
}

protected function setTheFoo($val) {
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
$obj->__get('the_foo');
$obj->__set('the_foo', 'myBar');
```

This bypasses the protected methods and goes directly straight to the instance variables.